# access data from old SSD from laptop

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive, raid

I would like to know if its possible to retrieve the data that I had from my ssd drive which was previously from my laptop. This ssd drive was in a Raid 0 config (with 2 X 128 SSD) which it was in my laptop and house my windows 10 OS and C drive, Desktop.

However, recently my motherboard died and I was planning to get a new computer so I took out this 2 ssd from my motherboard, hoping I can access the data externally from another computer. I bought a dual mSATA usb 3.1 enclosure with RAID 0 / 1 support and was place both the ssd in it.

When I connect this external ssd drive to my other computer, I could see it and initialize it but I could not access my previous data inside. Under Disk Management, The file system for this is RAW. How can I access it or turn this drive back to NTFS to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that the RAID support on your enclosure doesn't use the same format as the RAID support on your old laptop.  Unfortunately this is typical of driver-based RAID, which has no standards and poor data recovery paths.

There may be ways to recover your data using third party programs that are meant for the purpose, but initializing the drives might have erased the RAID header information and replaced it with whatever format the enclosure uses.  At this point you may have to either hire a data recovery company (expensive!) or try and look at the raw block data to see if you can recreate the original array (very challenging).  Other than that, your data is likely gone.

Comment: I found some free data recovery software from EASEUS, Minitool. I will try them to see if I am able to retrieve from my hard disk